# Retrieve list of subscription plans from stripe with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-cashier

How to obtain a list of subscription plans from stripe with Laravel 5.4?

Is there even a way to retrieve a list of subscription plans?

the following checks if a user is subscribed to a plan

```
@if(Auth::user()->subscribed('dailyTest'))
```

but is there something like

```
@foreach (Stripe::plans() as $plan)
```

Comment: I'd also welcome this feature.

Answer (score 13):

In your controller you should be able to do the following:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
$plans = \Stripe\Plan::all();
```

`$plans` will contain a collection of all the plans that are set up in Stripe.